# redirect not working after doing db updation in codeigniter4

Tags: php, redirect, codeigniter-4

My program in codeigniter4 does a db updation which after running successully I put a `return redirect()->(projectdetail)` , but the program shows only a blank page.No redirection happens .
My Code:

```
if($update){
            echo "updating...";

            $projectstatusdetail=$db->table('tbl_projectstatusdetails')
                        ->where('int_projectID',$int_projectID)
                        ->where('int_statusID',$status)
                        ->get()->getRowArray();
            $id=$projectstatusdetail['id'];

            $db->table('tbl_projectstatusdetails')
                 ->where('id',$id)                 
                 ->update($data);

            echo "update completed";//exit;     

            return redirect()->to('projectdetail');



        }
```

The code prints updating and update completed. But the redirection is not working. How to fix this? .When I did the same in another place where db insertion happens the redirect works.

Comment: "*the program shows only a blank page*", but also "*The code prints updating and update completed*" ...?  Those contradict each other, which of these is true?  Do you mean the code **should** print that text, but it doesn't?

Comment: A blank screen could mean there is a PHP error.  You need to display or find the error in the logs to understand what the problem is.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911552/php-blank-white-page-no-errors, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php.

Comment: What context is this code running in?  Is it a method in a controller?  https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/controllers.html

If the page is truly blank, and does not show at least "updating", then the problem is obvious - your first test `if($update){` evaluates as false.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return redirect()->to('url');
```

if you are using route then use

```
return redirect()->route('named_route');
```

or

```
return redirect()->to(site_url());
```

Please try go to your app->Config->App.php file and then change the  $baseURL to your running port like

```
public string $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
```

and then try the above code hopefully this will work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: None of the methods work

Comment: OP is already using the first of the examples you give: `return redirect()->to('projectdetail');`

Comment: Please try this your local project go to app->config->App.php file and change the $baseURL to your running port like     public string $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'; and then try. it will work for me.